# Find the seller of a product in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am using `spree`, and my `ruby` skills are not helping me. Each product has a `product property`, where the property is named: `Seller`.

Here's the model map:

```
Product has many ProductProperty

ProductProperty belongs_to Property

Product has many Property through ProductProperty
```

I want to do `Product.includes(:seller)`, where the seller is the `ProductProperty` where `Property.name = 'Seller'`

My incorrect attempt is right now at:

```
base.has_one :seller, -> { joins(:properties).where(spree_properties: {name: 'Seller'}) }, inverse_of: :product, class_name: 'Spree::ProductProperty'
```

Edit: Sample queries if the code worked:

```
SELECT "spree_products".* FROM "spree_products" WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2
SELECT "spree_product_properties".* FROM "spree_product_properties" INNER JOIN "spree_properties" ON "spree_properties"."id" = "spree_product_properties"."property_id" WHERE "spree_product_properties"."product_id" in [$1] AND "spree_properties"."name" = $2
```

Comment: Why not just put a foreign key column on the products table? I get using the EAV pattern for columns that are dynamic but in the case is it really necessary?

Comment: I could do that, but I don't want to change Spree's code models to prevent any ui changes to spree backend.

Comment: what's the query you get in the console when you try to access your `seller` relationship ?, do you mind posting that in the question ?

Comment: @fanta My definition of the has_one :seller is currently wrong. But if it were to run, it would produce something like in the edit in the question above

Comment: yeah, I know it does not work. So, do you get any errors when you try to access that relationship ?, what is the error in case you get it. If you don't get any error, you should be getting the SQL executed for that relationship. Sorry, I don't know Spree, but I do know that `base.has_one...` is the way to go if you want to extend the Spree core code.